# Why does ; suppress Dynamic output?

Tags: dynamic

`Dynamic[x=7];` does not make `x` dynamic! But `Dynamic[x=7;]` makes `x` dynamic with initial value 7. The problem with the later is the  presence of `Null` in the output. My question is: how can I assign a (big) value (or a huge list, etc.) to a dynamic variable AND suppress any possible output (including `Null`)?

Comment: What's the point of Dynamic then ?

Comment: Have you investigated `DynamicWrapper`?

Comment: Read the tutorials on `Dynamic`. There's no such thing as a dynamic variable. There's only stuff that shows as the dynamically updated "current" value of an expression, and in the process of calculating that current value, it might update other "non-dynamic" variables

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate.  (It is a common problem therefore "too localized" is inaccurate.)  If anyone has a suggestion for a *better* duplicate (on Mathematica.SE) let me know.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, actually it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179430/why-wont-this-work-dynamic-in-a-select/1581155#1581155

Comment: @Ajasja I'm well aware of that, as you will see if you review my answer below and the question this one now redirects to. ;-)  That's why I specifically said "on Mathematica.SE."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I apologize, I'm lacking a bit of eloquence today: I guess what I wanted to say was: "Could we not copy that answer to mma.se?". But there was probably some discussion on meta about such a policy already...

Comment: @Ajasja I see.  [Go recommend it!](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/744/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [Done](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/944/745)

Answer (score 3):

#### `Dynamic` doesn't work the way you think it does.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1581155/618728) for a full explanation.

In short, `Dynamic` doesn't do anything until it is actually displayed on screen.

Answer (score 1):

`Dynamic` is only updated if it is displayed. `Dynamic[];` is never displayed so it is never updated. `Dynamic[...;]` returns a dynamic that always returns `Null`, but is never the less updated.

Here is an example that demonstrates the problem:

```
x = .5;
Dynamic[Print["will not print:", x]];
Dynamic[Print["Should print:", x];]
Slider@Dynamic@x
```