# Working with DynamicModule: ScheduledTasks with local variables

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, scoping, scheduling

I have a question - is it possible to run `ScheduleTask[]` inside `DynamicModule[]`?

What I have tried so far:

```
DynamicModule[
   {i = 0, task},
   {
       Button["Run",RunScheduledTask[Dynamic[++i], 1]],
       Dynamic[i]
   }
]
```

It was supposed to increment and display value of `i` after `"Run"` was clicked, however it did not.

If you run `ScheduledTasks[]` you can notice that the task **was** created however it is not running... Any idea how to fix this one (if it is possible)?

Ok, thanks for answers guys however I have one more thing troubling me. What if I want to run specific, predefined tasks? E.g.:

```
DynamicModule[{i = 0, t1, t2},
 t1 = CreateScheduledTask[++i, 1];
 t2 = CreateScheduledTask[StopScheduledTask[t1]; --i];

 Dynamic@Row[{Button["Run t1", StartScheduledTask[t1]], 
    Button["Run t2", StartScheduledTask[t2]], " ", i}]
]
```

Of course this one is just an error generator but it presents general concept of what I would like to achive;p I would be grateful if you fix and explain this last one for me!

Comment: You can confirm with `Print` that the task does run. As Kuba says, the problem is that the argument of `Dynamic` is not evaluated. The second problem is that `Dynamic[i]` does not seem to realize that `i` is changing value, which you can fix with `Dynamic[i, UpdateInterval -> 1]`.

Answer (score 9):

#### Some notes

- First of all `Dynamic[++i]` does nothing unless it is displayed, and `ScheduledTask` is evaluated in Kernel without sending `DynamicBoxes` to the `Notebook`.

  You can read more about that in:

  - [**Why does ; suppress Dynamic output?**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20691/5478) or in tutorials:
  - [**IntroductionToDynamic**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html)

  **Correct syntax**: use `ScheduledTasks[++i...]`

- There is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) that affects crude `Dynamic[var]`, where `var` is a `DynamicModule's` variable.

  It makes `Dynamic[var]` not aware of changes of `var` unless they are done via *PreemptiveLink*, it is discussed in

  - [**What is the difference between Dynamic[x] and Dynamic[ h[x] ] for DynamicModule variables?**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/5478)

  **Quick fix:** use e.g.: `Dynamic[ First @ List @ x]`.

#### The answer

> What if I want to run specific, predefined tasks?

I'm not 100% sure why the message:

> ```
> StartScheduledTask::timnf : Specified task ScheduledTaskObject[
> Unique ID : 18 Repetitions : \[Infinity]] is not found.
> ```

is generated but here is my (quite solid) guess and the solution:

- Explanation

  It seems that `ScheduledTasks` are not found by mentioned `id` but the full form of the `ScheduledTaskObject`. And the object you created is different than the one which is called from the `Button`, here it is why:

  The problem is that `i` is fully scoped (by `DynamicModule`) when the `DM` is displayed (DynamicModule converted to DynamicModuleBox).

  When the body (2nd argument of DM) with your definitions evaluates `DynamicModule` scopes similarly to `Module` so it creates `x$123`. Yet at the end it will rename it again to `x$$123` (shortly, it is a longer topic).

  `ScheduledTaksObjects` in `ScheduledTaks[]` contain reference to this `i$123` while `DynamicModule` keeps `ScheduledTaskObjects` which underwent the second stage of scoping and `i$123` was replaced with `i$$123` (more or less).

  We can check that this is really the case:

  ```
   DynamicModule[{x, t},
      t = CreateScheduledTask[x++, {1}];
      Button["Show tasks", 
         Print @ Column @ {
           InputForm @ t, 
           InputForm @ First @ ScheduledTasks[]
         }
       ]
   ]
  ```

  > [image]

  Knowing that, and knowing that `Initialization` is sent to the evaluation after that second stage of scoping, we can deduce the fix.
- **Quick fix:** move your definition to the `Initialization` of `DynamicModule`.

#### Final fixed code:

```
DynamicModule[ {i = 0, t1, t2},
 Column[{
   Button["Run t1", StartScheduledTask[t1]], 
   Button["Run t2", StartScheduledTask[t2]],
   " ",
   Dynamic @ First @ List @ i}]
 ,
 Initialization :> (
   t1 = CreateScheduledTask[++i, 1];
   t2 = CreateScheduledTask[StopScheduledTask[t1]; --i];
   )
 ]
```

#### Further reading

For more detailed discussion of a closely related issue, take a look at:

- [**ScheduledTask with scoped variables. Working with timed evaluation**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38291/5478)

  Read comments under István Zachar's anaswer too, there is a lot of information.

Answer (score 4):

Scheduled tasks work fine within `DynamicModule`. For the past 3 years several schools here have trialled a Mathematica based final year math exam which included nested tasks (for reading time, writing time, restarting and so on) within one large dynamic module.

```
 DynamicModule[{i = 0},

 Column[{
   Button["Run", 
    RunScheduledTask[++i; 
     If[i == 6, 
      RunScheduledTask[CreateDocument["Hello world"], {1}]], {1,6}]],
   Button["Stop",
    StopScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
    RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]]
    ],
   Button["Reset", i = 0],
   Dynamic[{i}]
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: Is there any public info about details of those projects?

Comment: @kuba depends what you mean by public info. By definition the state education system know about it. WRI know about it. The code is not public. The exam is distributed to schools by SFTP on exam day.

Comment: I mean something that one could learn something from :)

Comment: @kuba i am on my phone now but can give a description tomorrow. I cant post the code but even though it is reasonably long it doesnt have anything that would be new to you

Comment: I see, you can e-mail me if you feel it is worth it ("1:eJxTTMoPChZiYGDILk1K1CvIT3FIz03MzNFLzs8FAGnMCHU="). I'm interested in how some 'backup' mechanisms can be solved. Exam is something serious so things like automatic backup, protecting ScheduledTasks from being removed by student with MMA knowledge, etc.

Comment: @kuba I can email if you like but for backup there was a scheduled task for autosaving every 2 minutes (plus a manual save button) plus multiple choice sections of the exam were stored as tagging rules and also exported as a file upon completion. A knowledgeable student, if the knew scheduled tasks were used, could of course stop all tasks but that would be the same as tearing up a paper exam. The menu was temporarily altered during the exam to limit what students had access to

Answer (score 2):

## WARNING

my original answer actually gives the wrong impression that there is a problem with `ScheduledTasks` and `DynamicModule` which actually is not the case, see my edit below the original answer. Of course my findings are just what Kuba has already found before. My (newer) code doesn't need the fix for the initialization as all code is in `Button` callbacks anyway. I would suggest the OP to accept Kuba's answer as it solves all the problems he originially had...

## ORIGINAL

I think you just found that `ScheduledTaskObject`s don't behave well when they are made local variables of `DynamicModules`. Here is code along the lines of what you try to do which seems to work (Mathematica 10.3 on Windows):

```
DynamicModule[{},
  i = 0;
  task = CreateScheduledTask[++i, 1];
  Row[{
    Button["start", StartScheduledTask[task]],
    Button["stop", StopScheduledTask[task]],
    Button["remove", RemoveScheduledTask[task]],
    Dynamic[i]
  }]
]
```

But as soon as you try to put either `i` or `task` into the list of local variables it won't work anymore. I find it not too surprising that this doesn't work, but as it nowhere is documented that it doesn't work, it might be considered a bug. A workaround is to use other ways to localize the variables you are using there...

## EDIT

I just realized that my answer and the one of Mike are in contradiction, me showing code that doesn't work while he is showing code which obviously works. So I tried to understand the differences and found that Mike is right with stating that the combination of `DynamicModule` local variables and `ScheduledTasks` in fact works well. The problem is with certain forms of `Dynamic`, as can be seen from my (slightly changed) example with localized variables which does **not** work as expected:

```
DynamicModule[{task, i = 0},
  Row[{
    Button["start",
      If[Head[task] =!= ScheduledTaskObject,
        i = 0;
        task = CreateScheduledTask[++i, 1]
      ];
      StartScheduledTask[task]
    ],
    Button["stop", StopScheduledTask[task]],
    Button["remove", RemoveScheduledTask[task]; Clear[task]],
    Dynamic[i]
  }]
]
```

But as it turns out the only problem is that the `Dynamic[i]` does not update as required. If we change it to `Dynamic[{i}]` as in Mikes working code the above code will work. A more general approach to fix this is to explicitly add the `TrackedSymbols` option as here:

```
DynamicModule[{task, i = 0},
  Row[{
    Button["start",
      If[Head[task] =!= ScheduledTaskObject,
        i = 0;
        task = CreateScheduledTask[++i, 1]
      ];
      StartScheduledTask[task]
    ],
    Button["stop", StopScheduledTask[task]],
    Button["remove", RemoveScheduledTask[task]; Clear[task]],
    Dynamic[i,TrackedSymbols:>{i}]
  }]
]
```

so I think this shows that there is no problem with using `DynamicModule` local variables and `ScheduledTasks` but that one has to be careful to not run into a problem with `Dynamic` which also has been discussed on this site before, see e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86393/169), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99696/169) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/169).

One final warning: if you use Mikes code naively in your own code you are in the danger to remove and stop scheduled tasks that might exist independently of the shown dynamic module. So it might be safer to use a local variable to remove and stop the given task than just to do that for all currently existing `ScheduledTasks[]`. Of course his code is perfectly fine for making his point in demonstrating that `ScheduledTasks` and `DynamicModule` local variables do work together and because they do it is easy enough to localize the scheduled task as in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

This functions

```
DynamicModule[{i = 0}, 
 Dynamic@Row[{Button["Run", RunScheduledTask[++i, 1]], " ", i}]]
```

**Update**

Run a predefined task

```
Module[{i = 0, t1},
 t1 = CreateScheduledTask[++i, 0.1];
 Row[{
   Button["Run  t1", StartScheduledTask[t1]], " ",
   Button["Stop t1", StopScheduledTask[t1]], " ",
   Button["Reset  ", i = 0], " ",
   Dynamic@i}]]
```

I didn't find a way to make this run inside a `DynamicModule`.

Comment: So this all was fault of misusing `Dynamic[]` wrap around `i`? But... why? Mayby I misunderstood the whole Dynamic concept but i thought if you want to see how the variable changes you should write it like `Dynamic[var]`....

Comment: `Module` approach won't work if you deploy it as a CDF or simply save the notebook with that interface. Next time you open MMA and this notebook, there will be no trace of `t1` definition.