# Dynamic scheduled task doesn't work

Tags: dynamic, scheduling

I have a list variable that I want to append new values from a normal distribution to after I click a button. It works in a simple case but not for the more complicated situation and I don't know why.

This works.. When I run it and press Start I can see the dynamic signal variable gets an extra '1' appended to the list every second.

```
signal = {};
DynamicModule[{task, μ, σ},
  task = CreateScheduledTask[AppendTo[signal, 1], 1];
  μ = 10;
  σ = 1;
  Panel[Grid[
    {{Button["Start", StartScheduledTask[task]], Null},
     {Button["Stop", StopScheduledTask[task]], Null},
     {"μ", Slider[Dynamic[μ], {0, 50}], Dynamic[μ]},
     {"σ", Slider[Dynamic[σ], {0, 10}], Dynamic[σ]}
  }, Dividers -> {False, {False, False, True}}]]
]

Dynamic[signal]
```

But what I'm actually interested in is appending a random variate from a normal distribution to the list. So I change the `task` variable to:

```
task = CreateScheduledTask[AppendTo[signal,
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, σ]]], 1]
```

But this doesn't work. Nothing is appended to the list.

Comment: @C.E. That doesn't change the behavior

Comment: What if you reverse the assignment of `task` and the assignment of the values to $\mu$ and $\sigma$? I suspect that $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are not defined when `task=...` is executed the first time.

Comment: @Felix No I actually tried that based on a previous comment. It doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Yes I agree this is a dup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually get an error message when I run your code with the `RandomVariate` task. It says:

> ```
> StartScheduledTask::timnf: Specified task ScheduledTaskObject[Unique ID:5,Repetitions: ∞] is not found.
> ```

The reason why your original code does not work seems to be that the `RandomVariate[...]` function delays the evaluation of the `task=` part of your code and hence `task` is not properly defined when the `Panel` is created. I must admit I don't fully understand why things are not evaluated in the sequence they are written, given that there is no `SetDelayed` involved. Anyways, there are multiple ways around this:

**1. Force immediate evaluation**

```
signal = {};
DynamicModule[{μ, σ}, μ = 10;
 σ = 1;
 task = CreateScheduledTask[
   AppendTo[signal, 
    Evaluate[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, σ]]]], 
   1];
 Panel[Grid[{{Button["Start", StartScheduledTask[task]], 
     Null}, {Button["Stop", StopScheduledTask[task]], Null}, {"μ",
      Slider[Dynamic[μ], {0, 50}], Dynamic[μ]}, {"σ", 
     Slider[Dynamic[σ], {0, 10}], Dynamic[σ]}}, 
   Dividers -> {False, {False, False, True}}]]]

Dynamic[signal]
```

**2. Define `task` in the global scope**

```
signal = {};
DynamicModule[{μ, σ},
 μ = 10;
 σ = 1; 
 task = CreateScheduledTask[
   AppendTo[signal, 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, σ]]], 1];
 Panel[Grid[{{Button["Start", StartScheduledTask[task]], 
     Null}, {Button["Stop", StopScheduledTask[task]], Null}, {"μ",
      Slider[Dynamic[μ], {0, 50}], Dynamic[μ]}, {"σ", 
     Slider[Dynamic[σ], {0, 10}], Dynamic[σ]}}, 
   Dividers -> {False, {False, False, True}}]]]

Dynamic[signal]
```

**3. Make sure `task` is defined in the initialization of the `DynamicModule`**

```
signal = {};
DynamicModule[{task, μ, σ},
 Panel[Grid[{{Button["Start", StartScheduledTask[task]], 
     Null}, {Button["Stop", StopScheduledTask[task]], Null}, {"μ",
      Slider[Dynamic[μ], {0, 50}], Dynamic[μ]}, {"σ", 
     Slider[Dynamic[σ], {0, 10}], Dynamic[σ]}}, 
   Dividers -> {False, {False, False, True}}]],
 Initialization :> (
   μ = 10; σ = 1;
   task = 
    CreateScheduledTask[
     AppendTo[signal, 
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, σ]]], 1];
   )]

Dynamic[signal]
```

Comment: Hmmm. That doesn't work for me. I'm on version 9. Maybe the behavior's been changed in a later version you have?

Comment: It works in version 10 and 11. Please clarify the version in your question (e.g., add a version tag) if you are looking for a solution specifically for that version.

Comment: Ok yes it works for me in version 9. I had changed something that screwed it up when I retested it with your answer.

Comment: I think this has something to do with [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103336/90). I've updated my code to put the `task` in the `Intialization` option of the `DynamicModule` and it works. Can you update your answer to do it this way since I think this is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: Interesting... Now that it works the problem is that the `μ` and `σ` variables are not updated when changed with the slider. If I stop the task and then start it again, it chooses the new values for those variables but they are not tracked on the fly as it's adding new values.

Comment: I see. It looks like `task` is created with whatever values μ and σ have at the time of assignment and then any association to the variable names μ and σ is lost. That makes sense since that is exactly what `Set` is doing. However, even by defining `task[μ_,σ_]:=...` I can't make it use the values of μ and σ from the slider. The only way that works for me is to define those variables in the global context (and then it works also with the `task=` `Set` assignment).